# How to remove all text in a line before and including an equals operator in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with lines containing various pairs like so:

```
abc/sdfsdf/include/sdfsdfg=include/defg/defgh
```

I am reading this file with a Windows batch script.

I want to remove everything from the above line up to and including the "=" symbol, so that I am left with the following:

```
include/defg/defgh
```

I tried the following:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\temp\entryfile.txt) 
do (
set string=%%A
set "string=!string:*\=include=\=include!"
echo !string! >> C:\temp\outputfile.txt 2>&1
)
```

I am using \ to try escape the = symbol. However it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%A in (C:\temp\entryfile.txt) do echo %%B
```

Using `=` as the delimiter, token `1` is assigned to `%%A` and contains the line up to the first `=` and `%%B` is assigned the remainder of the line after the `=`